# what is the difference between karma and phantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner

I know that Karma is a test runner for JS Unit Testing frameworks like Jasmine or Mocha. And PhantomJS provides headless browser for running Jasmine or Mocha Tests.

But, what is the difference between Karma and PhantomJS? Are they two competing tools, or do I use PhantomJS on top of Karma to run my unit tests without a browser?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

PhantomJS has nothing to do with testing. In the unit testing scope it would become one of the target browsers.

PhantomJS allows you to run unit tests in a browser when a desktop environment doesn't exist.

Karma is a *runner* that provides the finished reports on how successful the tests where.

Jasmine is the library used to write unit tests.

So to clarify

**Jasmine** *unit tests* are run by **Karma** inside the browser **PhantomJS**.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you have somewhat already answered your own question, but I'll expand what you have mentioned.

Karma is a test running framework that is largely test framework language agnostic.  It has a rich plugin ecosystem that allows you to heavily customize how, when, and why your tests run.

In order to test Javascript, we often need to test against an incarnation of the DOM.  There are numerous plugins that allow you to wire into different browsers such as karma-chrome.  These plugins bootstrap the required browser and execute your tests against the browser.

However, there are times when you want to run without a physical browser being installed on the target test box.  this is where PhantomJS comes in.  It is a headless browser that can be run without being installed on a target machine.  It cannot replace Karma.  If you want to describe it as a "competitor", it would be a competitor to IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: So if I need to run my tests on browsers (for example on developers laptops), I would use only Karma, and when I want to run my tests on my CI server, I would use Karma+PhantomJS?

Comment: You still should target/need to target a browser on developer's laptops.  PhantomJS works just fine, as does chrome.  Keep in mind that if you need to debug your tests (and you probably will), Chrome or another browser is much easier.  Personally I run https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher on my dev machine and https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher on Ci servers.